# Flex bar chart with Two Y axis

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts

I am trying to create a bar char in action 3 script.
But for some reason I am getting 2 y-axis and no x axis.

Can some one help spot the error.
I have said "placement " bottom.

The chart creation method is "getBarChartData", 
this method when invoked creates a barchart and adds it to a canvas.

This section is visible completely and can be called on a button click.

For some reason, the CDATA section is interfering with the preview of the snippet.

The standalone code snippet is below.

```
[Bindable]
 public var QUANTITY:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
   {date:"22-Aug-05", quantity:1575.9},
   {date:"23-Aug-05", quantity:1603.},
   {date:"24-Aug-05", quantity:1507.1},
   {date:"25-Aug-05", quantity:1568.8},
]);

private function getBarChartData(evt:MouseEvent):void{

 var title:String = "ASDFZXCVB";


 var pnlChart:Panel = new Panel();
 pnlChart.title = title;
 pnlChart.height = 750;
 {
  var categoryAxisDate:CategoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
  categoryAxisDate.categoryField = "date";

  var linearVolumeAxis:LinearAxis = new LinearAxis();
  linearVolumeAxis.minimum = 1500;
  linearVolumeAxis.maximum = 1700;

  var colChart:ColumnChart = new ColumnChart();
  colChart.showDataTips = true;
  {

   var horizontalAxisDateRenderer:AxisRenderer = new AxisRenderer();
   horizontalAxisDateRenderer.axis = categoryAxisDate;
   horizontalAxisDateRenderer.placement = "bottom";

   var quantityRenderer:AxisRenderer = new AxisRenderer();
   quantityRenderer.axis = linearVolumeAxis;
   quantityRenderer.placement = "left";


   colChart.horizontalAxisRenderers.push(horizontalAxisDateRenderer);

   colChart.verticalAxisRenderers.push(quantityRenderer);


   {
    var quantityColumnSeries:ColumnSeries = new ColumnSeries();
    quantityColumnSeries.horizontalAxis = categoryAxisDate;
    quantityColumnSeries.yField="quantity";
    quantityColumnSeries.displayName ="QUANTITY";
    quantityColumnSeries.dataProvider = QUANTITY;
    quantityColumnSeries.verticalAxis = linearVolumeAxis;

    colChart.series.push(quantityColumnSeries);


   }

  }

  pnlChart.addChild(colChart);
 }

 canvasReportId.addChild(pnlChart);
}
```

]]>

```
           <mx:Button label="Submit" click="getBarChartData(event)"  x="293" y="4"/>
          </mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Something looks off w/ the code you've pasted.. there seem to be stray curly brackets throughout it. Are those in your real code, or was that a pasting error?

Comment: I did paste the whole working code, but it appears that the CDATA imports are not being recognised. when i try to edit the post I do see the code in there, but the preview is not showing it. What can be done to fix it.

Comment: I just verified again, 
I have the x axis defined.
I have associated it with renderer.
And is added to column Chart.


horizontalAxisDateRenderer.axis = categoryAxisDate;
colChart.horizontalAxisRenderers.push(horizontalAxisDateRenderer);

quantityColumnSeries.horizontalAxis = categoryAxisDate;


What Am i missing ? An help is appreciated.

Comment: Also, If you change placement from "bottom" to "Top", the axis shifts from left to right.
But leaves us with 2 y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add it with MXML like so:

```
<mx:ColumnChart id="chart" dataProvider="{QUANTITY}">
 <mx:horizontalAxis>
       <mx:CategoryAxis 
            dataProvider="{QUANTITY}" 
            categoryField="date"
        />
 </mx:horizontalAxis>
</mx:ColumnChart>
```

This worked for me...
Ladislav

Comment: Yes, it works for me too. But there is a lot of other action script code associated and it will take time to convert to mxml.
Also, the actions script closely resembles this.
Still cannot make out why the mxml works and not as3.

Comment: Have you tryed adding horizontalAxisDateRenderer.horizontal = true

This would indicate that it is a horizontal axis rather than vertical one.

Seems to me that vertical is default...more on this on Adobe Flex page:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/AxisRenderer.html

Comment: That was the final line needed . No other change . Thank you.
Out of curiosity, why doesn't the property get set automatically when we push it into horizontalrenderes?

Comment: That is a good question, and I would not know the answer to that one..

Glad that it finally worked for you